# Parse.com REST API in Java (NOT Android)

Tags: java, parse-platform

I am trying to use the Parse.com REST API in Java. I have gone through the 4 solutions given here https://parse.com/docs/api_libraries and have selected Parse4J. After importing the source into Netbeans, along with importing the following libraries (which Netbeans told me I needed):

```
org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1
org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.2
org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.1
org.json:json:jar:20131018
commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9
junit:junit:jar:4.11
ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:0.9.28
ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:0.9.28
```

I ran the example code from https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/parse4j

```
Parse.initialize(APP_ID, APP_REST_API_ID); // I replaced these with mine

ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
gameScore.put("score", 1337);
gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
gameScore.save();
```

And I got that it was missing org.apache.commons.logging, so I downloaded that and imported it. Then I ran the code again and got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:120)
at org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies.process(RequestAddCookies.java:122)
at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:131)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:193)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:85)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at org.parse4j.command.ParseCommand.perform(ParseCommand.java:44)
at org.parse4j.ParseObject.save(ParseObject.java:450)
```

I could probably fix this with another import, but I suppose then something else would pop up. I tried the other libraries with similar results, missing a bunch of libraries. Has anyone actually used the Parse.com REST API successfully in Java? If so, I would be grateful if you shared which library/s you used and anything else required to get it going successfully.

Please do not suggest anything you have not tried. It will probably get me going in circles again.

I am using Netbeans.

Thanks.

Comment: REST APIs are *just* HTTP calls (and yes, I use them from Java). Your logger isn't setup (so you haven't actually got useful messaging yet). I would recommend you use a tool like maven or gradle or sbt or ivy to manage your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Elliott. I was referring to the API for Parse.com. Have you used this / does this function in the same way?

Comment: I haven't used the Parse.com API, but I can tell your logs aren't setup (that's the Exception you have posted anyway). Have you tried using a debugger? You mentioned Netbeans, so [here's one way](https://netbeans.org/features/java/debugger.html).

Comment: Don't think I've ever used one. Is there one built-in to Netbeans?

Comment: You say my logs aren't setup. What should I be looking for when using the debugger to fix this?

Comment: The debugger won't help you setup your logs, but for that try a search for "simple logging facade howto"

Comment: Is there an important reason the title reads 
"(NOT Android)"?

Comment: The error that you are getting is caused by the version incompatibility between logback and sl4j. Can you download the latest logback and sl4j jars and try running?

Comment: sphanley, under the Java section of APIs there are several for Android. The Parse.com API is often used for Android. I just wanted to clarify that this was a desktop app not an Android one, as the code is different.

Comment: Hirak, I updated to org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7, ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.13, ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.2, and also updated slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7 (I added this (1.7.1) after posting the question). Running the code yields exactly the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have the parse docs confused. Your title says "Rest API" . Yet , your code's from the parse ANDROID SDK!

1. figure out what interface at parse you will use and then use it ( ANDROID OR REST )
2. dont mix Android code into a Java/HTTP/REST client to parse.com
3. Practice some of  the curl CLI examples out of the REST API manual and you will know what sequence ( put them into a shell script ) of native command line http/curl expressions you want to submit to parse.
4. learn how to implement native httpclient in your java . I would suggest some kind of [async callbacks](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client)
5. transfer the sequence of Curl command line calls on parse.com into your java process and you will get the same result.
6. You must be able to log WIRE/ HEADERS with http  in order to develope in this environment.

sample code from android _ modified quickly to be near compatible on pure java:

```
//runnable inside the httpclient's implementation of 'exec'
    public void run() {
        int httprc = 999;
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setConnectionManager(YourConnectionMgr.getInstance())
                .addInterceptorLast(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
                    public void process(
                            final HttpRequest request, 
                            final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException { 

                            if(request.getRequestLine().getMethod() == "GET"){                                                                                                  
                                    request.addHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", ParseApplication.key_appId);
                                    request.addHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", ParseApplication.key_rest);
                                    request.addHeader("X-Parse-Session-Token",prefs.getString("default_parse_user_token", ""));
                                }

                    }
                })
                .build();   

        try {                       
            HttpResponse response = null;
            switch (method) {
            case GET:
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                httpGet.setProtocolVersion(new ProtocolVersion("HTTP", 1,1));
                httpGet.setConfig(this.config);
                response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, context);
                break; }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler,
                    HttpConnection.DID_ERROR, e));
        }
```

Comment: OP said he is using Parse4J... You can verify this in the stacktrace: org.parse4j.ParseObject.save(ParseObject.java:450)  Parse4J uses very similar naming as the Android API.  Parse4J works just fine, as long as the classpath is correct.  I don't really see how this answers the question.

Comment: This is not the answer to this question.